Appspec.yml not behaving the same as console
On EC2, I setup a virtual environment called 'venv' to run python.
I'm trying to add new package to python env with codeDeploy appspec.yml.
From appspec.yml (full code below), after updating requirements.txt, I run as ec2-user
source venv/bin/activate
cd /home/ec2-user
pip install -r requirements.txt

It does not update the python packages in venv.
But after deployment, when I open the console as ec2-user and run the same commands, it does update the packages in venv.
Here is my appspec.yml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /airflow
    destination: /home/ec2-user/airflow/
  - source: requirements.txt
    destination: /home/ec2-user
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 30
      runas: ec2-user

and start_server
source venv/bin/activate
cd /home/ec2-user
pip install -r requirements.txt
which python
airflow db init
cd /home/ec2-user/airflow
airflow webserver &
disown
which python
airflow scheduler -D

which python from appspec.yml returns /venv/bin/python
Same launched from the console as ec2-user
Roles and environment look iso but still does not work.
requirements.txt is correctly updated before running pip.
What could that be ?
Thanks !
